# How can I correct for color blindness accessibility with a Compiz color filter?

Tags: gnome, compiz, colors, accessibility

I want to be able to correct for red-green color blindness like in the gnome-mag applet, but I also want to use compiz, which doesn't allow for the color switching that gnome-mag provides (try it).

In the compizconfig settings manager, there is a Color Filter plugin that simulates deuteranopia and protonopia for normal sightedness people but I want a color filter that goes in the "opposite" direction.

Where are some filters for compiz that accomplish this?

Comment: Some color blindness tests: http://colorvisiontesting.com/online%20test.htm#demonstration card

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: closure? What is that? Not sure how that helps solve the problem. At the time, I researched this enough to narrow down the available software and I'd hate for someone else to repeat the same research.

Comment: You might want to consider editing your question to include examples of your reference material. The compiz software is lacking compatibility with gnome 3. Unless something changes and devs become more involved this issue will die.

Comment: A more direct way of phrasing that would be "gnome 3 is incompatible with compiz and you [should stop|won't be] using it". That said, I would love to hear about how gnome3 is going to support color blind users.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).